# Configuring native libraries for EAR in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I have a large project with multiple modules, which is deployed to glassfish using an EAR bundle (I'm using the Eclipse IDE).

One of the modules is an EJB project, which depends on a JAR library that depends on a some native libraries (DLLs). The DLLs are included in the jar

The problem I'm having is that the native libraries are not found. It seems that `java.library.path` doesn't contain the folder I configured in `project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> the jar -> Native library location`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but I found 2 workarounds.

1. Embed the DLLs into the JAR / EAR / WAR, and load them using [this loader](https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils), which basically gets the DLL using the `Class.getResourceAsStream` method, copies it in a temporary directory, and loads it from there (this is the method I chose).
2. Add the DLLs to system `$PATH`. Either put the folder where they are located in the `$PATH` environment variable, or copy them in a folder that is in `$PATH`.